# Serial tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The situation at [serial](/questions/tagged/serial) is a bit confused.  While most of the questions seem to refer to [serial-port](/questions/tagged/serial-port), there are some that are actually about [serial numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155734/writing-hard-drive-serial-string-to-binary-file), [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158397/equivalent-of-gcd-serial-dispatch-queue-in-ios-3-x) in multithreading, and probably other similarly named topics.

I'm planning on going through, retagging anything that relates to serial ports with [serial-port](/questions/tagged/serial-port), and then once I've figured out what's left, retagging as appropriate.

So please let me know if you have any suggestions or objections, and if not, join in the fun!

Comment: I've started hacking away at this a bit - there are some pretty interesting issues that people have with serial ports.

Comment: I keep a few RSS feeds handy for these cases. A lot are easy since they are usually split tags (like [tag:serial] and [tag:port]). With their powers combined, they are [serial-port!](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=serial+port&sort=newest)

Comment: The RSS feeds - a great idea!

Comment: Also discovered yesterday, search for one tag and the other word. So [`[serial] port`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bserial%5D+port) and [`[port] serial`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bport%5D+serial).

Comment: And this is done, for the no one following along.